# LU factorization of a singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, gaussian-elimination, lu-decomposition

I am trying to find the LU factorisation of the following matrix: $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 3 & 6 & -3 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Note that $A$ is singular.

I proceed with Gaussian elimination:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 3 & 6 & -3 \end{pmatrix}\implies \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 2 & -4 \\ 0 & 6 & -12 \end{pmatrix}\implies \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 2 & -4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Gaussian elimination has not provided an upper triangular matrix, $U$, so how can an LU factorisation be aquired?

Comment: $$\text{L = }\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 1 & 0 \\
 3 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),  ~~\text{U = }\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 3 \\
 0 & 2 & -4 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @Moo Crap. I mistakenly thought the main diagonal could not contain any zero entries for the matrix to be considered upper triangular.

Comment: It is upper triangular, see: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/UpperTriangularMatrix.html

Answer (score 1):

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 3 & 6 & -3 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
 a& 0 & 0\\ 
 b& c &0 \\ 
 d& e & f
\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}
 1&0  &3 \\ 
0 & 2 &-4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
 multiply it and equate to original matrix and find $a,b,c,d,e,f$